# IsSaleable always true for all products in Wishlist and Compare

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I have certain products that I want as in store only, so I added a boolean attribute to them and modified the IsSaleable check to look for that. This works fine in the product view but for the Wishlist and Compare pages the add to cart button still shows up and $product->isSaleable() always returns 1. For the compare page it even lets the customer add the product to the cart (in wishlist it just puts up a red error).

I'm looking at the /template/catalog/product/compare/list.phtml and /template/wishlist/item/column/cart.phtml files and I know they are the right ones since commenting out the button in them works on the site.

Answer (score 3):

See `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Compare_List::getItems` method. The boolean value that you added most probably isn't loaded in the collection, and so the `isSalable` call on the product returns 1 instead of what you expect it to be.

Make sure that the following line
`->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())`

in the `getItems` method returns your attribute. And if you're using flat products (which you should be doing) that the attribute has got a column in the `catalog_product_flag` table (by setting the attribute `Used in Product Listing` to `Yes`).

Same goes for whishlist. Let me know if that worked

Comment: That was already in there from default in the compare page. I'm not seeing anything similar in the wishlist group; there is a getProduct() function under block_item_configure but it just calls the catalog_model_product.

Comment: So to clarify, if you debug `$product->isSaleable()` on compare and wishlist pages, is your custom boolean attribute loaded?